# ia-Endomorphisms of metabelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \langle a, b \rangle$ be a two generated metabelian group so that $G/[G,G] = \langle a[G,G] \rangle \times \langle b[G,G] \rangle$ (direct product), where $[G,G]$ denote the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Now assume $[G,G]$ be abelian and set $c := [a,b]$. Now consider the ring of ia-Endomorphisms given by
$$
{\mathrm{ia}}(G) = \left\{ \varphi \in {\mathrm{End}}(G) ~:~ g^{\varphi} \in g[G,G] {\mathrm{~for~all~}} g \in G \right\}
$$

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the automorphisms of $[G,G]$ induced by the conjugation of $a$ and $b$ respectively and let $A$ denote the subring of Endomorphisms of $[G,G]$ generated by $x, x^{-1}, y, y^{-1}$.

${\bf{\mathrm Question:}}$ Show that $[G,G]$ is a faithful, cyclic $A$-module generated by $c$.

The cyclic part follows easily from the fact $[G,G] = \langle [a,b]^g, [b,a]^g ~:~ g \in G \rangle$. I am trying to argue why it is faithful.

Clearly $A$ is a commutative ring with identity and hence ${\mathrm{Ann}}([G,G]) = {\mathrm{Ann}}(c)$.

Now let $f \in A$ so that $c^f = 1$ in $[G,G]$. Since $[G,G]$ is abelian, we can express $f$ as a commutative polynomial in $x,y$ with non-negative powers. This is where things are getting out of control:

if we write $f = \sum_{(\nu)} \alpha_{(\nu)} x^{\nu_1} y^{\nu_2}$, then $c^f \equiv c^{\sum \alpha(\nu)}$ mod $[G,G,G]$. Also, there is no a-priori assumption that $G$ is nilpotent. The deeper expressions of $c^f$ modulo $\gamma_i(G) = [\gamma_{i-1}, G]$ for $i \geq 3$ are more and more complicated.

The discussion is from the article:

> A. Caranti and C.M. Scoppola, *Endomorphisms of two-generated metabelian groups that induce the identity modulo the derived subgroup*, Arch. Math. (Basel) **56** (1991), no. 3, 218-227.

I don't have access to Szekeres's article referred there for these arguments.

Comment: $A$ is a commutative subring of the ring of endomorphisms of $G' = [G, G]$. So if $c^{f} = 1$ for some $f \in A$, then for every $g \in A$ we have $(c^{g})^{f} = c^{g f} = c^{f g} = (c^{f})^{g} = 1^{g} = 1$. Since $G'$ is a cyclic $A$-module, $G' = \{ c^{g} : g \in A \}$, hence $f = 0$ is the trivial endomorphism of $G'$, as it sends all elements of $G'$ to $1$.

Comment: Actually, the fact that $G'$ is a faithful $A$-module follows trivially from the fact that $A$ is defined a ring of endomorphisms of $G'$. In the previous comment I showed that an element $f \in A$ is determined by its single value $c^{f}$ on $f$.

Comment: A priori my mistake was to see the ring $A$ being quotient of the full non-commutative polynomials on $x$ and $y$.  Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome. Please do not hesitate to ask more questions. Although I co-authored the paper thirty years ago, I should be able to go though it reasonably quickly.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti it would be useful if you post an answer rather than answer in comments.

Comment: @YCor, I will as soon as I can.

Comment: @YCor, done, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Here is another possibly simple riddle I could go past: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811203/independence-property-of-generators-2-generated-metabelian-groups

Comment: @Siddhartha, I have taken a look at the other post. It seems that in the paper there is a _clearly_ too many. Will try and think about it. In any case there is an alternative proof in Catino, F.; Miccoli, M. M.
A note on IA-endomorphisms of two-generated metabelian groups.
Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova 96 (1996), 99–104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$Taking the suggestion of @YCor (thanks!), I am posting my comments as an answer.

$A$ is defined as a subring of the ring $\End(G')$ of endomorphisms of $G' = [G, G]$, so $G'$ is a faithful $A$-module by assumption.

Moreover, $G'$ is a cyclic $A$-module, generated by $c = [a, b]$. In fact, $c^{A}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (as $A$ contains the automorphisms induced by conjugation by $a$ and $b$) contained in $G'$, and $G / c^{A}$ is abelian, as $[a, b] = c \in c^{A}$. It follows that $c^{A} = G'$.

Finally, if $f, f' \in A$ and $c^{f} = c^{f'}$, then $f = f'$. In fact, as $c^{A} = G'$ every element of $G'$ can be written as $c^{g}$, for some $g \in A$. If $c^{f} = c^{f'}$, then, exploiting the fact that $A$ is commutative,
$$
(c^{g})^{f} = c^{g f} = c^{f g} = (c^{f})^{g}
= (c^{f'})^{g} = c^{f' g} = c^{g f'} = (c^{g})^{f'},
$$
hence $f = f'$.